# Task fails with no way to debug

Tags: chainlink

I have a node running two jobs - they communicate with an external adaptor and then send the value on-chain.

One job works fine, which already tells me that the node can write on-chain.

The other job, receives the request, talks with the external adaptor (I have verified this on the external adaptor server) and then doesn't submit anything on-chain.

There is no way to debug this through the Operator UI. This is what it shows:

[image]

What should I do? I am running the Chainlink develop version because the most up-to-date stable version as a critical bug.

Answer (score 0):

In the Chainlink node version 1.8.0, there are "Error" and "Runs" tabs in your node UI in the browser, and these 2 tabs allow you to view what's wrong with your job run. You can find the latest chainlink docker image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/smartcontract/chainlink/tags).

[image]

The error messages under the "error" tab are shown below, and the info can reflect the error your job encountered in the run.

[image]

If there are no "error" and "run" tabs in the browser or there is nothing shown in the UI, you can also find error info in the log file housed by the server running the Chainlink node. The default path of the Chainlink node log file is `/chainlink/chainlink_debug.log`, so you can log into the server that running the node and check the log for debugging.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am now on the 1.8.0 version. There is no Errors tab maybe because the task is not labelled with an Error. It's running (for hours and hours) and doesn't give any error.

Comment: I can't find `chainlink_debug.log`, I am running docker and it looks empty

Comment: Hi @JoãoAbrantes, I tried 1.8.0 on docker and I can find the log file /chainlink/chainlink_debug.log can you check the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO3O6ZUtwbs to see if there is any difference when set up the chainlink node in docker?